# How to fit a linear ODE system?

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, nonlinear, modeling

Consider the equations
$$
\begin{align}
b'(t)=p_1 c(t)-k_1b(t),\\
c'(t)=p_2b(t)-k_2c(t)
\end{align}
$$
Given data on $b$ and $c$, and initial conditions, how do I find the best fitting parameters $k_1,k_2,p_1,p_2>0$? The following code constructs a function `sol` for the solution in terms of parameters $k_1,k_2,p_1,p_2$.

```
times = {0, 5, 10, 15, 25, 40};
bdata = Transpose[{times, {1481, 1421, 1236, 1506, 1512, 1490}}];
cdata = Transpose[{times, {915, 926, 875, 847, 915, 940}}];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   b'[t] == -k1 b[t] + p1 c[t],
   c'[t] == -k2 c[t] + p2 b[t],
   b[0] == bdata[[1, 2]], c[0] == cdata[[1, 2]]
   }, {b, c}, {t, 0, 40}, {k1, k2, p1, p2}]
```

My attempt: I have tried creating a model

```
Clear[model];
model[k1_, k2_, p1_, p2_][t_] := 
  Through[sol[k1, k2, p1, p2][t]] /; 
   And @@ NumericQ /@ {k1, k2, p1, p2};
```

and `NonlinearModelFit`, or even `FindFit`, but somehow I am not getting the arguments right. Somehow, the following seems to work relatively fast, but I am sure something can be improved

```
model[k1_?NumericQ, k2_?NumericQ, p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ] :=
 Sum[(sol[k1, k2, p1, p1][[1]][times[[i]]] - 
      bdata[[i, 2]])^2 + (sol[k1, k2, p1, p1][[2]][times[[i]]] - 
      cdata[[i, 2]])^2, {i, Length@bdata}]

fit = Last@
  NMinimize[{model[k1, k2, p1, p2], 
    Thread[(# > 0 &)[{k1, k2, p1, p2}]]}, {k1, k2, p1, p2}]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using your data `bdata, cdata`and solution `sol` try

```
J[k1_?NumericQ, k2_?NumericQ, p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ] := 
Total[Map[(sol[k1, k2, p1, p2][[1]][#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 &, bdata]] + 
Total[Map[(sol[k1, k2, p1, p2][[2]][#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 &, cdata]]


NMinimize[J[k1, k2, p1, p2], {k1, k2, p1, p2}]
(*{47080., {k1 -> -0.902959, k2 -> 1.09577, p1 -> -1.48543,p2 -> 0.665674}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I want strictly positive parameters. Should I simply add `Thread[(# > 0 &)[{k1, k2, p1, p2}]]}` to your code?

Comment: Yes! But `NMinimize` doesn't find a solution for that case!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: I run your code in my MAC M1 and find `{46397.7, {k1 -> -1.15061, k2 -> 1.36888, p1 -> -1.88922, 
  p2 -> 0.833338}}` different from yours. Why do you think?

Comment: @TugrulTemel Perhaps a version issue. Mine is v12.2 on Windows11

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Maybe you are right! My system is `Mac M1 max`. Percentage difference between your parameter values and mine is so large about 30%. Can such a big deviation be attributed to system differences? Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Different Mathematica version!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Yes, that is the reason I suppose. My version is v13.1.